# How to modify amazon aws EC2 Launch template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a EC2 launch template on Amazon's AWS that I really like. However I need to modify it. But after a lot of looking around I can't see how to modify it. How do I modify my launch template?

Sorry I am quite new to EC2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS doesn't allow you to edit every field for existing Launch Templates.

You can use the `modify-launch-template` command from the AWS CLI, but it has some restrictions to the fields you can modify.

Instead, you can create a `new template version` based on your previous one.

1. Create launch template
2. What would you like to do? => Create a new template version
3. Launch template name => (Select your original template)

Comment: Thanks, what a wierd way to do things huh?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new version of your launch template from the base configuration whenever you want, for example updating the ami source. Using the CLI:

```
aws ec2 create-launch-template-version --launch-template-name some-name-launch-template --launch-template-data '{"ImageId":"ami-08ebbb9b96a9afxxx"}'
```

And to trigger a rolling update , to the Autoscaling group use the new image use [instance-refresh](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/compute/introducing-instance-refresh-for-ec2-auto-scaling/):

```
aws autoscaling start-instance-refresh --auto-scaling-group-name some-name
```

Just ensure when you are defining your Auto Scaling Group for Launch template version, choose  the Auto Scaling Group uses the latest version of the Launch Template.